# c++ insert char at the beginning of char

Tags: c++

My (stupid) situation:

```
char numbers[3][10] = {"ONE", "TWO, "THREE"};
char letters[2][3] = {"A_", "B_"};
char comb[3][13] = {};
```

How can I create a new char array `comb` by adding in one line of code the letter "A" before all numbers?

Expected output: `comb = {"A_ONE", "A_TWO, "A_THREE"};`

What I tried, but does not work:

```
comb = letters[0] + numbers;
```

**Important boundary**: I can not use std::string (plenty of solutions with string in this site). Any simple solution for a beginner in C++? Thank you in advance

Comment: Avoid character arrays and use `std::string` instead.

Comment: can you use strcat?

Comment: @Ron. As I pointed out, I can't.

Comment: @MuhammadUmarFarooq I will try. Can you post a simple example?

Comment: Certainly cannot be solved *in one line of code*. Why do you have that restriction?

Comment: @john Why not? All C++ programs can be written in a single line, can't they?

Comment: As @Kaldrr pointed us can use **std::strcat**, Code:

```for(int i=0; i<3; i++) std::strcat(comb[i], letters[i]), std::strcat(comb[i], numbers[i]);```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
comb = letters[0] + numbers;
```

This doesn't work as you're trying to add a `char*` to `char**`, and assign it to `char**`.

As you pointed out that you can't use `std::string`, so you should use `strcpy` and `strcat`. Like that.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3 ; ++i)
{
   std::strcpy(comb[i], letters[0]);
   std::strcat(comb[i], numbers[i]);
}
```

You need to make sure that `comb[i]` has enough space to fit the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following algorithm:

```
For each index i of numbers
    let l be length of letters[0]
    copy letters[0] into comb[i]
    copy numbers[i] into comb[i], starting from index l
```